# Store app settings in Database

Tags: asp.net, appsettings

We have lot appSettings in our asp.net application. Is it a good idea to move them to database. I know one advantage is it is easy to maintain and do administrative activities. I need to know if someone has faced any issues.

Comment: I hope your database string is not in an appsetting ;). Depending on the use it will be slower to access them in the database.

Comment: @peer I do not agree on your point about slowness. Have you done any measurement on that?

Comment: Slower initially, but when cached they should be just as quick.

Comment: @Bumble Bee: Accessing a database is normally slower as a local resource. We do not know how they are used in this specific scenario, only in general. Normally I would prefer to make custom configurations for different components, not putting them in appsetting. Reuse and documenting them is far more easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have any appsettings in the config but maintains a seperate DB table as the amount of configuration is huge. There is no issue with that. Of course we have to use some caching to prevent too much of queries related to config information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to reduce the number of app settings, and make them easier to maintain. Each of them has its own positive and negative. Moving them to a db is one, which can help to improve the maintainability ( and can allow you to build a front end to monitor and tweak them without requiring a recycle ). Alternatively, you might want to group some of them into custom sections, if they are related, and so make them better documented, and not just key value pairs.

If they go in the db, you need to consider caching them, and how you should manage the cache.

There is no general answer. It will depend on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using an app.config / web.config / database / cache / custom solution to store configuration values are all valid options.

Which method you choose really does depend on what's right for you, your team and your application in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that doing this would give you a performance hit as appSettings are loaded into memory what the application is loaded and then reloaded if the web.config is updated. If you stored them in a database then you would need to hit the database everytime.

I couldn't give an indication of the level of performance difference so it may or may not be an issue.

Comment: @Bumble Bee - Granted but you are then relying on something to invalidate the cache entry or you will have a lag in the settings being updated. My expectation is that reloading would be quicker and use fewer resources than loading from a DB. I suspect that the benefit depends on your setup. E.g. if you have the application over a number of servers then it would be easier from an admin perspective to have these saved on a central DB.

Comment: True, but in our case we have implemented the invalidation within the Setters and you are correct about the maintainability. We have like hundreds of configs so it would have been a nightmare to have them as appsettings.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net has a mechanism for implementing a custom provider for config. I've looked into this for a scenario where multiple servers need the same config, so having a shared config would be good. there was very very little documentation on it.

You also face the issue that web.config files are watched, so any changes prompt the app to restart. With a DB you'd need an alternate mechanism for this, or work around it or just do without.

Far simpler is to define a custom config section.

Simon

Comment: What is this machanism for implementing a custom config provider?